# Visual Studio: Failed to Deploy to HoloLens 1 (DEP6957)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, deployment, hololens

Been trying to deploy one of my projects onto the Microsoft HoloLens 1 via USB. For some reason, I keep getting an error about remote authentication: "DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode.. etc."

I'm using Bootcamp on a Macbook Pro + HoloLens 1 with Visual Studio 2019.

Things I've done:

- Developer Settings on Both HoloLens1 and Laptop.
- Clean/Rebuild solution.
- Pair HoloLens to Laptop with the Microsoft HoloLens desktop app.
- Selected x86 & Debug with deploy to DEVICE.
- Both devices on same Wifi network.
- HoloLens connected via usb.

Really hoping someone can help! I've gone through most of the forums online and they all say more or less the same things which I've already done. I've attached some screenshots as well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDATE: Installed the USB Device connectivity on Visual Studio and am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

We think this issue may happen due to the lack of USB Device connectivity component in Visual Studio and the following steps worth trying for you.

1. Check if the component USB Device connectivity has been installed for your VS. If not installed, you can install it with Visual Studio Installer.
2. Unpair all devices in Setting from your HoloLens.
3. Deploy your project to your device, the first time Visual Studio deploys it, you will be prompted for a PIN. Follow the [Pairing your device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio#pairing-your-device) instructions.

Comment: Looks like I haven't installed the USB Device connectivity for VS. However, I have just installed it and did the steps you've listed but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: @monochromatic Could you please check if the HoloLens OS is upgraded to the latest version?  Correspondingly, the target Windows SDK version on the VS side also needs to check whether it matches the HoloLens OS. Besides, after connecting through USB, could you go to https://127.0.0.1:10080 from a web browser on your PC to access Windows Device Portal?